# How to shift development of an existing MVC3 app to a TDD approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd

I have a fairly large MVC3 application, of which I have developed a small first phase without writing any unit tests, targeted especially detecting things like regressions caused by refactoring. I know it's a bit irresponsible to say this, but it hasn't really been necessary so far, with very simple CRUD operations, but I would like to move toward a TDD approach going forward.

I have basically completed phase 1, where I have written actions and views where members can register as authors and create course modules. Now I have more complex phases to implement where consumers of the courses and their trainees must register and complete courses, with academic progress tracking, author feedback and financial implications. I feel it would be unwise to proceed without a solid unit testing strategy, and based on past experience I feel TDD would be quite suitable to my future development efforts here.

Are there any known procedures for 'converting' a development effort to TDD, and for introducing unit tests to already written code? I don't need kindergarten level step by step stuff, but general strategic guidance.

*BTW, I have included the web-development and MVC tags on this question as I believe these fields of development can significant influence on the unit testing requirements of project artefacts. If you disagree and wish to remove any of them, please be so kind as to leave a comment saying why.*

Comment: TDD is all about Design Driven Development and is not the same as unit tests. See http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/its-not-tdd-its-design-by-example.html Write unit tests for your existing code and all new planned code use TDD(Design By Example)

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com, Thanks, but I do understand the difference. TDD does however use unit tests as a driver for development, and both TDD and unit tests form part of my question.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com I'll stick to the original meaning of TDD, aka "Test Driven Development". I worked in an XP team for several years. We discussed this a lot and realized that at some point, a majority of changes to the system wasn't new code, but modifying existing code. TDD is just as valuable here. TDD produces unit tests more often than not as one will often mock out dependencies to test a unit of code. TDD confirms a design (which is in your head). You don't necessarily have good design because of TDD. I would not confuse the process of TDD with that of design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any existing procedures, but I can highlight what I usually do.

My approach for an existing system would be to attempt writing tests first to reproduce defects and then modify the code to fix it.  I say attempt, because not everything is reproducible in a cost effective manner.  For example, trying to write a test to reproduce an issue related to CSS3 transitions on a very specific version of IE may be cool, but not a good use of your time.  I usually give myself a deadline to write such tests.  The only exception may be features that are highly valued or difficult to manually test (like an API).

For any new features you add, first write the test (as if the class under test is an API), verify the test fails and implement the feature to satisfy the test. Repeat.  When you done with the feature, run it through something like [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/). It will often highlight things you never thought of.  Be sensible about which issues to fix.

For existing code, I'll use code coverage to help me find features I do not have tests for. I comment out the code, write the test (which fails), uncomment the code, verify test passes and repeat. If needed, I'll refactor the code to simplify testing. [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) can also help.

Pay close attention to pain points, as it highlights areas that should be refactored.  For example, if you have a controller that uses ObjectContext/IDbCommand/IDbConnection directly for data access, you may find that you require a database to be configured etc just to test business conditions. That is my hint that I need an interface to a data access layer so I can mock it and simulate those business conditions in my controller. The same goes for registry access and so forth.

But be sensible about what you write tests for. The value of TDD diminishes at some point and it may actually cost more to write those tests than it is to give it to someone in India to manually test.

Comment: Good points, thanks. My client is a cheaper tester than someone in India though. I must just draw him up a UAT check-list to run through every time I complete a sprint.